# How to convert EBCDIC with chinese chars to UTF-8 format

Tags: utf-8, ebcdic

I have a requirement to convert a file with EBCDIC encoding which is encoded using the IBM937 code page to UTF-8 format for loading the file into a multi-byte enabled DB2 database.

I have tried unix recode and iconv. None of them has the ability to convert IBM 937 to UTF8. I'm looking for any utility (java, perl, unix ) in this world which can do that on a unix based system. Can someone help me here?

SL

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ICU (International Components for Unicode): http://site.icu-project.org/

It has a converter for IBM-937: http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/convexp?conv=ibm-937_P110-1999&s=ALL

> CU is a mature, widely used set of
>   C/C++ and Java libraries providing
>   Unicode and Globalization support for
>   software applications. ICU is widely
>   portable and gives applications the
>   same results on all platforms and
>   between C/C++ and Java software. ICU
>   is released under a nonrestrictive
>   open source license that is suitable
>   for use with both commercial software
>   and with other open source or free
>   software.
>
> Here are a few highlights of the
>   services provided by ICU:
>
> - Code Page Conversion: Convert text
>     data to or from Unicode and nearly any
>     other character set or encoding. ICU's
>     conversion tables are based on charset
>     data collected by IBM over the course
>     of many decades, and is the most
>     complete available anywhere.
> - Collation: Compare strings according
>     to the conventions and standards of a
>     particular language, region or
>     country. ICU's collation is based on
>     the Unicode Collation Algorithm plus
>     locale-specific comparison rules from
>     the Common Locale Data Repository, a
>     comprehensive source for this type of
>     data.
> - Formatting: Format numbers, dates,
>     times and currency amounts according
>     the conventions of a chosen locale.
>     This includes translating month and
>     day names into the selected language,
>     choosing appropriate abbreviations,
>     ordering fields correctly, etc. This
>     data also comes from the Common Locale
>     Data Repository.
> - Time Calculations: Multiple types of
>     calendars are provided beyond the
>     traditional Gregorian calendar. A
>     thorough set of timezone calculation
>     APIs are provided.
> - Unicode Support: ICU closely tracks
>     the Unicode standard, providing easy
>     access to all of the many Unicode
>     character properties, Unicode
>     Normalization, Case Folding and other
>     fundamental operations as specified by
>     the Unicode Standard.
> - Regular Expression: ICU's regular
>     expressions fully support Unicode
>     while providing very competitive
>     performance.
> - Bidi: support for handling text
>     containing a mixture of left to right
>     (English) and right to left (Arabic or
>     Hebrew) data.
> - Text Boundaries: Locate the positions
>     of words, sentences, paragraphs within
>     a range of text, or identify locations
>     that would be suitable for line
>     wrapping when displaying the text.
>
> And much more. Refer to the ICU User Guide for details.

Comment: thanks for the response, any example help on converting ebcdic to utf8  for reading chars from a file?

Comment: Not in java. The .Net world has the System.Text.Encoding class that provides support for conversion between different encodings. The Microsoft framework has support for [some] EBCDIC encodings, but not IBM 937. No idea what Mono (open-source .Net) supports...or how difficult it would be to write a custom encoding. The .Net way is to read an array of octets and hand that to the encoder/decoder and get a string in return. The EBCDIC double-byte stuff complicates it because of the need to deal with shift-in and shift-out between single- and double-byte modes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Java can convert the IBM937 code page to UTF-8.

You would specify the input format as "cp937".

Here are two methods from the Oracle page on [Character and Byte Streams](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html):

```
static String readInput() {

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis,
                          "cp937");
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
            buffer.append((char)ch);
        }
        in.close();
        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
static void writeOutput(String str) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
        out.write(str);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This one initally didn't work. When I imported the icu4j charset libraries and reran, it seem to have run fine. however, my chinese ebcdic chars don't seem to have gotten converted the way it's supposed to be? Any thoughts?

Comment: The original characters are something like:
凧刡凮剭勄剭刣剭刡匎刪 ?僔働っ牼  僉僌僑僒匎刪 ?僔働っ牼  僉僌僑僒?    

After conversion i get something like:
 ブイピーシーエーインクＶＰ�ㄣ　ＬＯＳＴンクＶＰ�ㄣ　ＬＯＳＴ     ブイピーシーエーインク

Comment: @SNL:  My first thought is, are you sure that the input is IBM937 (CP937)?  There are a few other IBM EBCDIC pages for Chinese characters.  There's CP1371, CP950, CP964, and CP948.

Comment: Yes, I did. Some of these above charsets don't seem to convert and the others seem to be giving the same result. Moreover, the transmitter confirmed that the file is sent using the codepage ibm937 only

Comment: @SNL: I'm stumped.  Maybe you can try UTF-16 as the output just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: still the same. let me triple check with the transmitter. thanks for the quick responses.